# pypi packaging and secrets: why does a github--intended .travis.yml hold a password?

Tags: python, security, travis-ci, packaging, pypi

I've always understood the rule #1 of secrets is you keep them out of public source control.

So, I was prepping to upload a new package to pypi.

In **.travis.yml** I see:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
  user: mysuser
    password:
    secure: PLEASE_REPLACE_ME
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: myuser/pynoorm
    condition: $TOXENV == py27
```

Fair enough, and I guess I forgot to replace it.

But... the part that is really puzzling is when I pick a **random .travis.yml** on github and it has:

```
ANzomjrVPkzLO7MG9Zekl1Tz/Gxxx ... HmSQ3GRNPHMIRqf1xle+8/0IwDBuC/eTsOkit7WU1j9lgurCj8snXuTLUVEqf/SecAcLpmLrelRFvz//ZcOopIbwD66RJWT8pYGBH/L3MMIDFj1bIf0UIpXdBXgeTJhxW054+BhdFPGI66IvWU/kOlOcE606wqRqI9bdvop34OewJFnOQ9El...71dROWO4ETzz1wGXmO0dTVfCWMbqk7dT8OPft+tHsWWJqqeCEL3wj1uYEIYpCwLo9oSyVXwrhzRW0dysZfTCx/XfDaws3eFA6iMg6dUoBt12kwGZ5vCbgjBwPOmQrRMUEmYoyZz8n20HKojoxzUpwueFN/nbLv76arJbN8bLeb/GyE6r1Rw0DEzs8f0fBtv5agUnIpMh6EPOFYN4rwHMxt52HU7BB/Kg=
```

What is the point of adding a *secure password* to a file that you are uploading to github?  What does it do?  I thought the usual process was to log into github and then link your account to travis.  In which case both services ought to know how to authenticate you, if you're logged into either one, without having to go through a password in a public settings file.

How dangerous/sensitive is this particular part of a github travis configuration?

Can I do without it?

The initial pypi package files were generated with CookieCutter cookiecutter-pypackage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repository’s `.travis.yml` file can have "encrypted values", such as environment variables, notification settings, and deploy API keys. These encrypted values can be added by anyone, but are only readable by Travis CI.

This is what the `secure:` field name indicates. It's safe to include these encrypted values in your `.travis.yml` and safe to upload them to Github as well.

You can generate secure values by installing the `travis` gem and running it:

```
$ gem install travis
$ travis encrypt "secretvalue"
<encrypted string>
```

Comment: ah, ah.  that makes sense.  still not really sure what it does though, but I feel a bit -ish for asking this question.  do you have info on what this bit is used for?  can I leave it out?

Comment: It's your PyPI password. Travis needs it to upload a package on your behalf.